# eZ Publish beginner

Tags: php, content-management-system, ezpublish

i am trying to learn eZ publish CMS , and i could not find any decent tutorials which is easy to understand and learn , plz if anybody could help me out with the links to any useful tutorials i would really appreciate it....

Comment: See http://ez.no/ezpublish/develop_with_ez_publish

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://ez.no/doc), althought a bit sparse in places, should cover enough to get you started.

What are you looking to learn? The content management/user side, template development, module development?

The latter completely lacks documentation, but you can pick up template development by taking a look at ezwebin (bundled with the installation) and looking at the [Reference section](http://ez.no/doc/ez_publish/technical_manual/4_x/reference) of the technical manual.

Answer (score 2):

2 links :

- [A great collection of up-to-date tutorials](http://share.ez.no/learn) : An Introduction to Developing eZ Publish Extensions, Creating a simple custom workflow event, A Quick and Friendly Introduction to eZPersistentObject, Fetching User Objects with PHP, Understanding and developing fetch functions, learning eZFind, etc.
- Some other eZ Publish Tutorial on [Siteground.com](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ezpublish/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this CMS or you want to develop it?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to http://doc.ez.no/.  Until I took the official eZ Publish Basics Training Course, I had a hard time grasping it as well. eZ language is not Smarty so don't try going that route. Read both the technical manual and user manuals which are currently written by Europeans so it's hard to read.  An American copywriter is re-writing them for easier comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

packt publishing also has an ez publish book available.

http://www.packtpub.com/Managing-eZ-Publish-Web-Open-Source/book

Answer (score 0):

Adding these links for more relevant times.

Those who wish to explore eZ Publish, it now sits on the Symfony framework (full-stack).

eZ Publish 4.x and older versions are now considered the "Legacy Stack" ("LS"). eZ Publish LS will be supported throughout version 5.x with fallback functionality however the support may be dropped on versions 6.x and LS may even be removed from the download package in versions 7.x.

So here are some links to get you started:

- [eZ Publish 5.x Documentation](https://confluence.ez.no/display/MAIN/eZ+Documentation+Center) which provides links to:

  - eZ Systems on GitHub
  - eZ Systems JIRA Tracker
  - eZ Publish on is on IRC: #ezpublish, irc.freenode.net
  - Symfony Documentation (for learning the framework's layout, yml, twig
    etc)
  - Share.ez.no: Read tutorials, blogs and forum posts on the share portal
- Get involved with the [North America meetup](http://www.meetup.com/eZ-Publish-Users-Developers/). We have monthly code
  shares and other meetups.